# MySQL select specific values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm searching a request to MySQL to get specific values from table.

```
select * 
from wp_posts v 
left join wp_postmeta pm on (pm.post_id = v.id) 
left join wp_posts p on (v.post_parent = p.id) 
where v.post_type = 'product_variation' and p.id = '1743' 
limit 0,100
```

This request output like this because `SELECT *`

```
ID ... |meta_key |  meta_value | ...     
1  ... _price    |  500        | ...
1  ... _regular  |  500        | ...
1  ... some another|  jfjfj    | ...
...
2  ... _price    |  500        | ...
2  ... _regular  |  500        | ...
2  ... some another|  jfjfj    | ...
```

I need to select id and meta_value from meta_key = '_price' only.

How to get it?

I try

```
select meta_value from wp_posts ...
```

But it gives me table with values. How to select only for one or two keys?

Need help please!

**EDIT**

Thanks Ankit Bajpai.

Adding in WHERE meta_key='_price' works.

One more question

How to get for meta_key='_price' and meta_key='some another' together?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Not error but not i want to see
I want to see id 1 meta_key '_price' meta_value '500'

Comment: #1052 - Column 'ID' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: you can add the meta_key = '_price' in where clause.

Comment: Ankit Bajpai I try it before, and get no results. NOW gets.

Comment: @AlexPain Show your whole query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select * 
from wp_posts v 
left join wp_postmeta pm on (pm.post_id = v.id) 
left join wp_posts p on (v.post_parent = p.id) 
where v.post_type = 'product_variation' and p.id = '1743' and
    and meta_key in ('_price', 'some other value 1', 'some other value 2')
limit 0,100
```

Comment: Yes ! it is what i want!